# I need a regular expression to find ranges between 622126-622925

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find ranges between 622126-622925

^622[126-925]$

Answer (score 5):

Assuming an inclusive range:

```
^622(12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9][0-9]|9[01][0-9]|92[0-5])$
```

But REs aren't really meant for numeric tasks, so I advise you to find a different solution.

Comment: I think I just proved my own point: there was a bug in the first try.

Comment: You've not considered `6222**`

Answer (score 4):

Although you could do that in theory, the regex would be so complex that it wouldn't be maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

```
^622(?:12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9][0-9]|9[01][0-9]|92[0-5])$
```

**Explanation:**

The prefix `622` is common. Removing it we need a regex to match `126 - 925`:

The range `126-925` can be split as:

```
  RANGE       REGEX
-----------------------------------------
126 - 129     12[6-9]
130 - 199     1[3-9][0-9]
200 - 899     [2-8][0-9][0-9]
900 - 919     9[0-1][0-9]
920 - 925     92[0-5]
```

Clearly this is not the way go about for this job. A simple comparison operator will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but the result will be ugly. Do you *really* need to use a regular expression for this?

So, anyway: as you correctly observe, the initial 622 is straightforward. Now, a number is between 126 and 925 if ...

1. ... it begins with 1, followed by something between 26 and 99; or
2. ... it begins with something in the range 2..8; or
3. ... it begins with 9, followed by something in the range 0..25.

And something is between 26 and 99 if ...

1. it begins with 2, followed by something between 6 and 9; or
2. it begins with something in the range 2..9.

And similarly for the range 0..25.

I'll let you put the pieces together because if you're going to inflict something like this on yourself (or whoever'll be maintaining the code) you ought to find out for yourself how painful it is. Please consider again: do you *really* need to do this with an RE rather than some other way?

Answer (score 2):

While that maybe possible, regexp is not really the right tool for that. It's better just to convert your string into number and use the normal number comparision of the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This was working for me:

```
'^(6011|622(12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-1][0-9]|92[0-5]|64[4-9])|65)'
```

> Source: https://creditcardjs.com/credit-card-type-detection

PS: You'll find there a much better solution if you use Javascript.